# Why Obj-C property default ownership "assign" instead of "strong"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm adding Swift classes to an old project. It went well, until I tried adding a property to the Swift class. The generated header doesn't compile.

[image]

I think the problem is, in the generated code, Swift omitted `strong` ownership and only declared it as `nonatomic`. This should normally be enough, because @property should default to `strong` ownership, right?

So basically these are equivalent:

- `@property (nonatomic) NSDate *aDate;`
- `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *aDate;`

But, in my case, it seems like it is defaulting to `assign` instead of `strong`, according to the compiler message.

I'm using Xcode 6 GM, and the project has ARC turned on.

Any idea why it is not defaulting to `strong`? Can I change this somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After numerous experiments, I've found out a subtlety that determines the default ownership behavior of a property:

- If a header file is imported **only into ARC-enabled** classes, and there is no default ownership declared, then the ownership of the property within this header file is `strong`.
- If a header file is imported into **at least one non-ARC** class, and there is no default ownership declared, then the ownership of the property is `assign`!

This means also, you must not import a `-Swift.h` header into any non-ARC classes, as it will change the behavior of all the properties and emit warnings (which in my case were converted to errors).

Pretty weird IMHO...

---

Example:

- we have classes `SourceClass`, `ARCClass`(ARC-enabled) and `MRCClass`(ARC-disabled)
- `SourceClass.h` has: `@property (nonatomic) NSDate *date;`

Subtlety:

- If we add `#import "SourceClass.h"` only in `ARCClass.h` or `ARCClass.m`,

  - the property `date` has ownership `strong`.
  - the declaration is equivalent to `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;`.
- As soon as we add `#import "SourceClass.h"` to `MRCClass.h` or `MRCClass.m`,

  - the property `date` **will have ownership `assign` instead**.
  - the declaration is **changed** to `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *date;`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that, at one time, "assign" was the default and this...

http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/b/b6/Objective-C_Programming_Language.pdf

*"assign -
    Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This is the default."*

...seems to confirm that (page 59).

However, I also see an Apple document ("Programming with Objective-C") that says, "By default, both Objective-C properties and variables maintain strong references to their objects".  I believe the change was made with the introduction of ARC.

Although you say ARC is turned on, if this project is old enough it may be that something is still around to interfere with ARC settings.

I realize this isn't a definitive answer but perhaps checking project settings (or cleaning up the project) with this change in mind may help.

Comment: Thank u! I'm also thinking in this direction... Is there any way to force Xcode cleanup the project settings? Or any tips which parameters I should focus on?

Comment: The only obvious one is "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" in the build settings.  If I switch that to NO in a sample project, I get the same kind of messages you do (though in ObjC).  When I switch to YES, they go away.  Other than the standard clean and delete derived data steps, I don't know any other tricks for this.

Comment: ARC can be turned off on a per-file basis, @zavié; that might be what's happening here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248351/how-can-one-turn-arc-off-for-specific-file

Comment: @PhillipMills FYI I found out that the crucial point is, whether this header file is imported into an non-ARC class. As soon as that is happened, the default is changed from strong to assign! And I don't think there's any way to change it... See my answer of this post!